# Paypals IPN.php Error

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-ipn

**The situation:**
Setting up a buy and download market on a website using paypal. 
I've already set up the "buy" and "checkout" buttons using paypals button creator. 
Now I need to create a IPN script to call paypal and verify purchase so the "product"
may start downloading. If there is a better direction in how to go about this, I would appreciate the suggestion.

**The problem:**
Paypals IPN sandbox simulator is giving me a 
"We could not send an IPN due to an HTTP error: 500: Internal Server Error"
yet, I still receive an "INVALID" response.

**The Question:**
How do I 
1) Fix Paypals IPN sandbox simulator to be able to send the message 
2) and receive a "VERIFIED response.

**The Scripts:**
I am using the exact script from paypals github
heres the link:

[paypal_ipn.php](https://github.com/paypal/ipn-code-samples/blob/master/paypal_ipn.php)

Thanks in Advance!

p.s.
I have come across some similar situations but none have work for me.

Comment: What do you mean that you receive INVALID?

Comment: Although the Simulator give me the 500 error message. In My FTP, I receive a .ipn log with the following:
INVALID
[2014-05-17 12:19 America/Denver] Invalid IPN: cmd=_notify-validate

Comment: a 500 ERROR usually means something went broken on the server, IPN is a pain to troubleshoot from my experience, What does your webserver logs show? (The logs that show the actual php errors).

Did you enable paypal IPN from your sandbox merchant account? (did you set the required URL in your paypal account?)

I'm not entirely sure why you would get a 500 error and still get a log, As far as I know that shouldn't happen.

can you manually visit the paypal IPN url? does it through any errors?

Comment: Yes, everything is configured. It may be the run script I created for the paypal_ipn.php?

Answer (score 0):

Your IPN script must have an error in it causing it to return the 500 back to PayPal's server.  Your script could be (and apparently is) handling most everything ok and saving your log file as expected, but then at the end something is causing the error so the script doesn't fully complete successfully.

The first thing I would do is solve that problem.  An easy way to do this is to create your own simulator by building a basic HTML form with hidden fields that match the names of the fields you expect to get from an IPN.  Set the action of the form to your IPN URL and then you can load this in a browser and submit it so that you can see the result on screen.  This can help with troubleshooting and fixing any errors you have.

Once you've solved all the errors you can try the simulator again and you should get a successful result at that point.  If you're still getting invalid, though, then you must have a problem with your callback to PayPal.  We can figure that out once the script is completing successfully, though, and that may very well fix both problems once you figure out whatever is going on there.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. 
Great idea! -I did as you said.
I created the html page with hidden fields and an action to the paypal_ipn.php script. 

Unfortunately, its still "INVALID".

Comment: Here is the error log. 
[19-May-2014 11:04:19 America/Denver] PHP Fatal error:  Class 'paypal_ipn' not found in public_html/test/index.php on line 4

Comment: It may be the code I created to run the paypal_ipn.php script. 
Here is my run script. [keep in mind this is a separate script from the paypall_ipn.php script. It is also located in the same directory.]
<?php
require 'paypal_ipn.php';
$paypal = new paypal_ipn('sandbox');
$paypal->run();
?>

Comment: First, I should have mentioned, when testing with your own HTML form the data will always come back invalid because it didn't originate from PayPal.  This method simply allows you to get rid of actual errors within the PHP code happening, which it sounds like you have.  It's not finding that class, so your include path must be wrong or something like that.

Comment: true. I've been researching why the path is not being recognized. 
None that have had solutions. Thanks for the response. I'll keep exploring.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using an PHP framework to implement PayPal IPN listener, then don't forget to put `exit;` statement at the bottom of the controller. If you don't write `exit` statement, then the framework will try to load the view file, and in my case there is no view file. That is why I got the 500 Error message in the PayPal IPN simulator.

Here is example of code that is running fine on my machine.

```
public function ipnlistener2Action(){
        // tell PHP to log errors to ipn_errors.log in this directory
        //mail('YOUR EMAIL', 'Invalid IPN', "Exception");
        ini_set('display_errors',1);
         error_reporting(E_ALL);

        // intantiate the IPN listener
        require_once('common/ipnlistener.php');
        $listener = new IpnListener();

        // tell the IPN listener to use the PayPal test sandbox
        $listener->use_sandbox = true;

        // try to process the IPN POST
        try {
            $listener->requirePostMethod();
            $verified = $listener->processIpn();

            if ($verified) {
            // TODO: Implement additional fraud checks and MySQL storage
            mail('YOUR EMAIL', 'Valid IPN', $listener->getTextReport());
        } else {
            // manually investigate the invalid IPN
            mail('amir.duran@ceit.co.uk', 'Invalid IPN', $listener->getTextReport());
        }


        } catch (Exception $e) {
            mail('YOUR EMAIL', 'Invalid IPN', "Exception: ".$e->getMessage());
            //var_dump("Exception");
            exit(0);
        }
        exit;

        // TODO: Handle IPN Response here
    }
```